# How to call EJB in PhaseListener

Tags: jsf, ejb

I use JSF 2 and EJB 3.1, all of them are deployed on Glassfish 3.1.

When i setup a class named MyInterceptor which is implemented PhaseListener, i can not revoke remote EJB interface inside it.

It notice "NullPointerException ..."

```
public class MyInterceptor implements PhaseListener {

@EJB(name="AuthorizationEJB", 
            beanInterface=AuthorizationService.class,
            mappedName="corbaname:iiop:localhost:3700#ejb/AuthorizationEJB")
public AuthorizationService authorizationService;

....

}
```

When I call authorizationService.dosomestuff(), it raise error NullPointerException

How can i do to fix it?

Thank in advance

Comment: i did it using my solution by call a Managed Bean that which can call EJB. Thank for your help again.

Answer (score 3):

In JSF 2.1 and earlier, PhaseListeners are unfortunately no injection targets (meaning you can't use injection in them). You can do your lookup programmatically via JNDI instead though.

In JSF 2.2 all JSF artifacts (including PhaseListeners) will be injection targets, but this will probably not help you now.

*Unrelated to your question, but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by specifying the `beanInterface` in your annotation. Most likely you'll also don't need the `name` attribute and if your bean is a local bean you'll also don't need `mappedName`.*

Answer (score 2):

Use a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) instead of a JSF phase listener to do authorization. You can inject an `@EJB` in a `@WebFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah in web filter you could have just used plain *@EJB*. Maximimum you needed to add *beanName* if you had two beans implement same *AuthorizationService* interface.
Servlet filter is per request, I don't think you need to do security stuff at a certain phase from JSF's lifecycle (which is a more granular level than the whole http request).

For normal lookup you can do:

```
AuthorizationService.class.cast(new InitialContext().lookup("corbaname:iiop:localhost:3700#ejb/AuthorizationEJB")).dosomestuff();
```

in a try catch javax.naming.NamingException