# How to get Resource Paths without FacesContext?

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, jsf-2

I'm trying to get the resource paths in a WAR file by using the method *getResourcePaths()* in *ExternalContext*. But how to do it if the method is called by `@Schedule`? In that case the FacesContext is null.

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "0,30", second = "0")
public void foo() {
  ExternalContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  Set<String> resources = ctx.getResourcePaths("/WEB-INF/");
  ...
}
```

I know that the FacesContext is only valid inside a request. Is there some other trick?

Comment: I hope you do not use `FacesContext` inside of your EJB classes.

Comment: I have xml documents in my resources that I want to use in an EJB service class. I don't want to hard code the file names in my application. So I wonder how to query these names programmatically (without using `FacesContext`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convention says that in three layers software architecture one layer may only access underlying layers but no overlying layers (the *very next* underlying layer in *strict* three layers architecture, *all* underlying layers in *flexible* three layers architecture). The only exception known to me is [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern): The subject notifies all attached observers when data has been changed. This is made with a *weak reference* from subject's layer to observer's layer.

My solution to the problem is, I wrote an Application Phase Listener (lying in ui layer of course) that scans the resources folder `WEB-INF` at application startup-time. This is legitim because application phase listener runs in faces context.

Phase listeners are no injection target up to JSF 2.1 (see [here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061342/how-to-call-ejb-in-phaselistener)). So it's necessary to get my EJB reference by JNDI. The EJB (lying in model layer) is then instanciated automatically.

Application Phase Listener:

```
@Override
public void processEvent(SystemEvent e) {
  if(e instanceof PostConstructApplicationEvent) {
    try {
      // getting ejb by jndi
      InitialContext iCtx = new InitialContext();
      EjbService ejbService = (EjbService) iCtx.lookup("java:module/EjbService");

      // fetching resources
      ExternalContext eCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
      Set<String> resources = eCtx.getResourcePaths("/WEB-INF/");

      // setting resources into ejb
      ejbService.setResources(resources);
    } catch(NamingException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Many thanks to all who have helped in answering my question.

Comment: You probably don't want to have your `EJBService` in that method. It means that the service lookup is done *everytime* the method is called, which is a bit wasteful and needless IMO

Comment: JNDI lookup is expensive, but I think it's ok here, because the event type `PostConstructApplicationEvent` is triggered only once at application startup-time.